# 新完全マスター(N3)　ぐらいきれいな　vs　ぐらい高い

Tags: grammar, jlpt

『新完全マスター(N3)』に出てくる問題「日本で富士山ぐらい＿山はないと思う。」の答えは「きれいな」ですか。

(１・きれいな　２・高い　３・ほかの)

Why not 高い?

Could you please explain this in detail?
(I was looking for an answer here but did not find)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think No.2 is a bit unnatural because it is a well known fact that Mt. Fuji is the highest mountain in Japan. So 思う is a bit unnatural. 日本で富士山ぐらい高い山はない would be natural. For example, it is a bit odd if American people say "I think the US borders on Mexico", isn't it? No.1 would be the answer.

Comment: Thank you.
I didn't think about the natural aspect.

Comment: We went about separate ways and came to the same conclusion somehow. Funny how that works. Though, this makes sense to me as well.

Answer (score 3):

As far as Shin Kanzen Master N3 is concerned, the correct answer comes directly from their definition of the grammar point:

> ～くらい...はない　～ぐらい...はない　～ほど...はない
>   「～がいちばん...」客観的な事実ではなくて、話者が主観的に言うときに使う。
>   ・リーさんぐらい動物好きな人はいない。
>   ・わたしは料理を作ることぐらい楽しいことはないと思っています。

emphasis: **主観的に言うときに使う**

(1) きれいな：主観的 (subjective)

(2) 高い：客観的 (objective)

Therefore, the answer must be (1).

Answer (score 2):

This might be a context call. However, here's your clue-in:

> 日本で**富士山ぐらい**＿山はないと思う。

It sounds to me like we're discussing the aspect of the mountain in of itself, not an attribute like its height (I might be expecting 富士山**の高さ**ぐらい if we were talking height).

But, the quickest way to see this as a context call is that, from prior knowledge, you know: 1. There are mountains about as tall as 富士山, for example, 北岳 or 穂高岳, however, both are shorter, and 2. To Japanese people, the most beautiful mountain in Japan is without question 富士山.

Recall that くらい is used for talking about approximation. This can certainly be used to talk about the height of something, or something that's calculable, but also certainly about the aesthetic of something. So, if there exist mountains that approximate the height of 富士山 but there aren't mountains that approximate the beauty of 富士山, this is the clue that completes the phrase.

Comment: `To Japanese people, the most beautiful mountain in Japan is without question 富士山.`いや～それはどうかなぁ。。。人によるのでは・・